# Help with regex

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Okay, this is almost a pure duplicate ... with one little piece of information that I just don't understand.

The original question is: [Sed Explanation: sed '/./,$!d' file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323948/sed-explanation-sed-d-file)

And relates to the following:

```
sed '/./,$!d' file
```

The explanation at that question is really good except for one thing (and I don't have the reputation to post a comment to the answer to ask for an expansion). what is the meaning of the comma?

I know this seems like a waste (a whole new question) but I have not been really able to figure it out otherwise (regex documentation argh! lol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comma in sed separates so called addresses in the address range.

`/./,$` means "From a line containing a character to the last line".

Comment: Thanks. That one small piece of information was all that was missing.

Comment: "Thanks" on StackExchange = upvote / accept.